# Откуда появилось озвучивание шахматной нотации?

Tags: этимология

В шахматах координаты поля принято передавать с помощью буквы латинского алфавита (горизонталь) и цифры (вертикаль), например, в начальной позиции белый и чёрный короли стоят на e1 и e8, соответственно.

Меня интересует откуда появилось следующее озвучивание букв латиницы:

A [а], B [бэ], C [цэ], D [дэ], E [jэ], F [эф], G [жэ], H [аш].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из французского языка, который был языком международного шахматного общения в конце XIX века. Впрочем, впрочем, тогда он вообще был основным международным языком. Аналогичные обозначения используются и математиками - и по тем же мотивам, только возрастом на два-три столетия поболее.

Если уж совсем точно, то это т.н. "французский" вариант произношения букв латинского алфавита (не путать с собственно французским алфавитом, отличия небольшие, но есть). 
А буква Е произносится как [jэ] только в русских реалиях, тут уж ничего не поделаешь, обычно это просто Э.